# UserProperties being shared between users in Google Apps Script published UI service

Tags: properties, google-apps-script

I am working on a google apps script that is being published as a service, and accessed by multiple users via the UI.

The problem I'm having is that when one user causes a UserProperty to be set, all the users subsequently have their UserProperty set to that also. In other words it is acting like a ScriptProperty, rather than a UserProperty, in that it is not User specific. All users appear to cause this to happen.

I have studies my code and I just cannot see that it is anything to do with that. I make no reference to EffectiveUser, so only ActiveUser could ever be setting these values.

My guesses are:
- I am misunderstanding the scope of UserProperties
- My variables have somehow become corrupted (I have had problems with other UserProperties variables doing some odd stuff)

Has anyone experienced this, or does anyone have any suggestions?

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 5):

UserProperties are better suited for scripts that run inside Spreadsheets and not published ones. The reason is that a published script runs under the user id of the user who created the script and not as the person who invokes it.

So, if the script is written by someone@example.com, then the UserProperty will be that of someone@example.com irrespective of who invokes the script. So, when one user writes a UserProperty, all others see the same value

Comment: They key is "published as a service".  Like Srik mentions, if you want the script to run under the context of another user, you need to have them explicitly execute the script (most typically from a spreadsheet).

Comment: Hi Srik/Matt. Thanks very much for your answers, that makes sense. I was working on the assumption that the userproperties related to the Active User rather than the Effective User (indeed such a set of properties would be most useful). OK, I'll have to go plan B.  All the best, Chris.

Comment: While deploying as a web app, Google Script asks you whether to Execute the app as: me or The user accessing the web app.